# Replace Contours from ContourPlot3D doesn't work

Tags: plotting, replacement

I try to replace number of contours in a plot already stored in a variable (or in a function, doesn't matter). I have very complicated and time-consuming calculations followed by plotting a ContourPlot3D, so I would like to avoid repeating that. Minimum working example:

`plot = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> 5,   PlotLabel -> "5 contours", Mesh -> None]`

[image]

then I try to replace label and contours - for labels, it works, but fails for contours:

`plot /. {(Contours -> ___) :> Contours -> 3, (PlotLabel -> ___) :>    PlotLabel -> "3 contours"}`

[image]

Why is that so?

Comment: You cannot do that. Option `Contours` is relevant only for the `ContourPlot3D`. After plotting, you get back `Graphics3D` which contains the geometric objects (contours), and the `Contours` isn't relevant anymore (it's not even present). You have to replot the whole thing again with `ContourPlot3D` because contours have to be recalculated.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for answear.

Comment: However, labels and the like can be changed using `Show`.  Also, removing specific contours without recalculating the rest is possible, although a bit of work.